# Generate JWT Token for logged in user?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, jwt

I have a razor pages app [username and password auth] and a WebAPI app that uses JWT auth. Both the services use the same user table. After user proceeds to checkout on the Razor pages app, I need to call an API in the WebAPI that that requires JWT. How can I generate this token for a logged in user in my razor pages app ?

Comment: this maybe help you : Implementing JWT Authentication in ASP.NET Core 5

https://www.codemag.com/Article/2105051/Implementing-JWT-Authentication-in-ASP.NET-Core-5

Answer (score 1):

Ali.Ahmadi's comment is useful, I also create a sample project and it works for me. I can use username and password to login, and get the jwt token. You can follow this article and use it in your razor pages app.

[Add a link to github to prevent links in comments from breaking.](https://github.com/joydipkanjilal/jwt-aspnetcore)

[image]

Then in your webapi project, you can create a [JWTMiddleware](https://github.com/JayKrishnareddy/JWTAuth_Validation/blob/master/JWTAuth_Validation/Middleware/JWTMiddleware.cs) to valid this token.

For more details, you can check the blogs, it contains detailed description.

[Create And Validate JWT Token In .NET 5.0](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-net-5-0/)